# does Stream class has Name property?

Tags: c#

```
using (Stream output = File.Create("sample.mp3"))
{
response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
url = output.Name;
Console.WriteLine($"Audio content written to file 'sample.mp3'");
}
```

I used Stream object and while debugging- I saw he has property Name-
The url (path).
But when I write in in code- it doesnt copmpiled.
I need the url of the Stream object. what can I do?
You cant see it here- but name is with red line under. can you help me? tanx.

Comment: `File.Create` returns a `FileStream` object which has a `Name` property.

Comment: Let's start with the basics. For this code, can you explain why `bob` doesn't at compile time have a `Length` property but `bob1` does? `object bob = "abc"; string bob1 = "abc";` That will help us target our answer appropriately.

Comment: I have the same problem here; not being able to access to ```Name``` property. It appears ```Stream``` and ```FileStream``` both have this ```Name``` property (although the ms documentation for Stream(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-7.0#properties) doesn't confirm that), but for some reason, the access to Name is only available in FileStream and not Stream itself.
Have you found out anything since you asked this question?